# Material UI Select, keep the scroll at top if all items are selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui

As described on the title, I'm looking for a way to keep the scroll at top because it seems that the default behavior is that it moves to the end when all items are selected, here is an example:

This is the default behavior:

[image]

Expected behavior:

[image]

I create a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wlqjpnqzj) if any one want to help

I looked for all options presented in the [api](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/) but no one of them helped, my idea is to get the DOM element directly and apply `element.scrollTo=0`

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @vijayscode no i don't, it's very complicated

Answer (score 2):

Set the `variant` to `menu` on the `<Menu>` to prevent initially selected items to change the scroll position.

See: [MultiSelect box popover keeps jumping when scroll or select items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785482/multiselect-box-popover-keeps-jumping-when-scroll-or-select-items)

Answer (score 1):

For the `Select` MUI v.5.X

```
<Select MenuProps={{variant: 'menu'}}>
  <MenuItem value={1}>One</MenuItem>
  {/* ... */}
</Select>
```