# MUI: Stop dropdown from jumping

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm using the [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) and [MenuItem](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item/) components in a next.js project.

I'm passing the "select" prop in the TextField. This makes the text field use the [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) component internally.

My problem is: The dropdown is jumping on the screen after clicking (the dropdown appears for 1 sec or so on the top left corner of the screen and eventually moves underneath the select field).

Here's my code:

```
         <div>
              <TextField
                focused
                sx={{ m: 0.5, width: 130 }}
                select
                id="birthdayD"
                name="birthdayD"
                label="Geburtstag"
                type="Geburtstag"
                SelectProps={{
                  MenuProps: {
                    sx: { maxHeight: 200 },
                  },
                  variant: "menu",
                  getContentAnchorEl: null,
                }}
              >
                {day.map((option) => (
                  <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                    {option.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
             </TextField>
    </div>
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785482/multiselect-box-popover-keeps-jumping-when-scroll-or-select-items) a great post about why I should use `variant: "menu", getContentAnchorEl: null`, but in my case the problem isn't solved.

Comment: I think you should also pass the `variant` and `getContentAnchorEl` to the `MenuProps` instead of the `SelectProps` since the `variant: "menu"` can't be used on the Select component.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it as well. Now I get the error "Warning: React does not recognize the `getContentAnchorEl` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `getcontentanchorel` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

Comment: `getContentAnchorEl` does not seems to be an attribute at all on the MUI components, if you search within the docs. You do have an `anchorEl` attribute

Comment: ...but even as lowercase the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but you just be able to use one of the examples from the docs:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#basic-select

Comment: Yes, this is an other way to do it. But my code is also from the doc (section select): https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Answer (score 0):

Change the `variant` prop to the `MenuProps` and remove the `getContentAnchorEl` since it is no longer in use in MUI v5

```js
<TextField
  focused
  sx={{ m: 0.5, width: 130 }}
  select
  id="birthdayD"
  name="birthdayD"
  label="Geburtstag"
  type="Geburtstag"
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      sx: { maxHeight: 200 },
      variant: "menu"
    }
  }}
>
  {day.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

Check here for a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-flower-dmqb00?file=/demo.js)

Comment: I've changed everything. And your example is working. But my problem is still there..I don't know, maybe it's something specifically related to next.js?!